# Analyze correlation between two multivariate time series with different number of variables

Tags: time-series, correlation, multivariate-analysis

I have two multivariate time series, one of which has 18 variables and the other one has 200 variables. Both the time series are of different lengths and were not captured simultaneously. I am not sure how I can perform correlation analysis between these two. Any pointer will be highly appreciated!

Comment: Are their time resolutions (acquisition frequency) at least equal?

Comment: No, they are not. One is 256Hz, the other one is 1000Hz.

Comment: Then I'm afraid it doesn't make any sense to compute correlation coefficients. There are other possibly interesting analysis, but a simple correlation is probably meaningless here

Comment: Yes, I agree with you. Can you give me a pointer to other possible analysis that I can perform to understand the relationship between these two time series? Thanks for your help!